# Play3d in RGL package

Tags: r, rgl

I am working on a project using the RGL package in R programming. I would love if someone could help me with the play3d function of the same.

Here is what I plan to do. I have a polygon3d(x,y,z) that plots a polygon on the output window and now I would want to translate it with some value at each iteration, say by 10 units for 5 rounds.

I researched but all the available resources are about rotation of the polygon for t-duration. Example of such a case is:

```
M <- par3d("userMatrix")
play3d( 
  par3dinterp(userMatrix=list(M,rotate3d(M, angle=pi, x=1 ,y=0, z=0))), 
  duration=10
)
```

The above code rotates my polygon along x-axis for 10seconds and stops.

I want to translate my polygon for 10 seconds with some given parameters specifying how much to translate at each second.

My polygon is basically a plus sign(representing a quadcopter) and I want to show the motion as if it is elevating from the ground(x-y axis) into the air(z-axis).

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the transpose of a translation matrix to do this.  For example, to translate by (x, y, z), use

```
M <- par3d("userMatrix")
play3d( 
  par3dinterp(userMatrix=list(M, M %*% t(translationMatrix(x, y, z)))), 
  duration=10
)
```

This is done in the ?rgl.setMouseCallbacks example.

Edited to add x, y, z values to answer question below.

Comment: Thanls for the help!! But can you specify how can I mention the units it should translate. I am actually unaware what the M-matrix is. Can you help me a bit with the translation part? :)

Comment: Thanks alot, I had tried that initially but the polygon returns back to its original coordinates(0,0,0). In other words, it re-translates back to its original position like a pendulum. Additionally, my translation distances is x=133, y=150, z=100, then the polygon flies right out of the screen.